# Proof of Bernoulli like inequality

Tags: inequality, proof-verification

I found this inequality and I would like to prove it:
$$ (1+x)^n \leq 1 + \frac{nx}{(1-(n-1)x)} $$

with with $n>1$ and $-1<x<1/(r-1)$.

Does anybody have an idea?

Edit:
I added the restrictions on x and n

Comment: Restrictions on $x$ and $n$?

Comment: Sorry I've added the restrictions on x and n

Comment: maybe consider changing $r$ to $n$.

Answer (score 2):

Since, we are required to show that $\displaystyle (1+x)^n \le 1+\frac{nx}{1-(n-1)x} = \frac{1+x}{1-(n-1)x}$,

i.e., $\displaystyle (1+x)^{n-1}(1-(n-1)x) \le \left(\frac{(n-1)(1+x) + (1-(n-1)x)}{n}\right)^n = 1$ (by Am-Gm inequality).